# bash script variable "$arch" = "x86" the string "x86" is being seen as a command

Tags: bash

This is literally my first thing ever programmed not including a hello world program so any help would be appriciated

I am trying to make a stupidly simple payload maker and it seems to be seeing a string as a variable and i would like some help

when i run it and type in `x86` it returns "line 12 x86: command not found"

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"

echo "Were you wanting to make a x86 payload or a x64 payload" 

echo "(enter x86 or x64)"
read arch

echo "you chose $arch"

if "$arch" = "x86"
then
        figlet lol    
fi
```

Comment: `if [ "$arch" = "x86" ]` You forgot the `[]`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs. `[` is an actual command.

Comment: I was going to suggest you use shellcheck.net, but it doesn't detect this error. Because for all it knows, `$arch` could be the name of a program.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if "$arch" = "x86"
```

to

```
if [ "$arch" = "x86" ]
```